# Client Components with NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to create a one page landing page that lets people upload videos and that has a filesize check prior to the upload.

I have this at src/app/page.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import FileUpload from '../FileUpload'; // Adjust the import path as necessary
import Image from 'next/image';

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center bg-[#f7f1e3] p-8">
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold text-[#1d3b2f] mb-10">Title</h1>

      <FileUpload />  {/* Use the FileUpload component here */}


    </main>
  );
}
```

And at src/FileUpload.tsx, I have this:

```
// Add this line to explicitly mark this component as a client component
/* @jsxImportSource @next/client */
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const FileUpload = () => {
  const [fileSizeOk, setFileSizeOk] = useState(false);
  const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState(0);

  const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = event.target.files?.[0];
    if (file) {
      // Check file size (500 MB = 500 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
      if (file.size <= 500 * 1024 * 1024) {
        setFileSizeOk(true);
        let progress = 0;
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          setUploadProgress(progress);
          if (progress >= 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
          } else {
            progress += 10;
          }
        }, 100);
      } else {
        setFileSizeOk(false);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      {fileSizeOk && <p className="text-green-500">✔ File size is OK</p>}
      {!fileSizeOk && <p className="text-red-500">✖ File size is too large</p>}
      <div className="bg-gray-200 rounded h-2">
        <div className="bg-[#1d3b2f] h-2 rounded" style={{ width: `${uploadProgress}%` }}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;
```

On this particular line:

```
        <div className="bg-[#1d3b2f] h-2 rounded" style={{ width: `${uploadProgress}%` }}></div>
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot find module '@next/client/jsx-runtime' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I'm not sure what to do -- how can i solve this problem and implement file size checking on the frontend?

Answer (score 2):

Please try 'use client' instead of /* @jsxImportSource @next/client */